# NiFi PutFile processor doesn't save file to a directory

Tags: apache-nifi

In my NiFi workflow I need to download .zip file from SOAP web-server, save it on machine (optional) and unpack content to sub-folder. Everything works on my local Win 10 machine, but issues occur when I try to move to remote Linux server. Here is the part of my flow when error happens:

[image: data enters UpdateAttribute]

So we have a FlowFile entered `UpdateAttribute` where filename attributed is set with required name and .zip extension. The file is correct as can be seen in queue after starting the processor.

Problems start happen when I pass the FlowFile to `PutFile` processors. I tried different scenarios based on selected directory:

relative to NiFi main folder **./out**:

```
12:30:01 MSK ERROR
PutFile[id=05788ae5-64e5-32af-bb40-88d50d4c886c] Penalizing StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=3e0c5e38-76f8-4ce3-b911-90f6901c35a4,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1586337594333-49, container=default, section=49], offset=2335, length=375628606],offset=0,name=,size=375628606] and transferring to failure due to /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/./out: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/./out

12:30:01 MSK ERROR
PutFile[id=05788ae5-64e5-32af-bb40-88d50d4c886c] Unable to remove temporary file /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/./out/. due to /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/./out/.: Invalid argument: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/./out/.: Invalid argument
```

Full path **/opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/** :

```
12:32:45 MSK ERROR
PutFile[id=0171102b-c82d-149d-c9ae-ea4da99b1750] Penalizing StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0573803f-8407-46e4-93f0-e52a5fc35a07,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1586337594333-49, container=default, section=49], offset=2335, length=375628606],offset=0,name=,size=375628606] and transferring to failure due to Failed to export StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0573803f-8407-46e4-93f0-e52a5fc35a07,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1586337594333-49, container=default, section=49], offset=2335, length=375628606],offset=0,name=,size=375628606] to /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. (No such file or directory): org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileAccessException: Failed to export StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0573803f-8407-46e4-93f0-e52a5fc35a07,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1586337594333-49, container=default, section=49], offset=2335, length=375628606],offset=0,name=,size=375628606] to /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. (No such file or directory)
```

So it adds dot ('.') to path which causes exception. All folders are created and permissions granted. I tried to run simple test flow with file of 42B and the same path (GenerateFlowFile -> PutFile) and everything is OK.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try add filename to your path ? /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/${fileName}

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help:
`/opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/out/file/. (No such file or directory)`

Comment: your ${fileName} is "." ? can you look at attribut while your flowfile is in queue

Comment: I've checked: filename is "fias_delta_dbf.zip". If I try to download content it is downloaded with this name. Nevertheless, PutFile process still adds '.' at the beginnig of the filename

Comment: I've tried to simply assign "upd.zip" to filename, but it didn't helped.
Also I delete 'filename' attribute, but '.' still appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Linux system rights: there was 'nifi' user for flow execution and one more user for accessing Linux filesystem.
Assigning `rwxrwxrwx` for used folders solved the issue.